# What is the correct syntax for this PHP based SQL statement?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following SQL statement which has been verified as working:

```
INSERT INTO community_players (community_id, player_id)
SELECT communities.id, users.id
FROM communities INNER JOIN users ON communities.admin = users.user_email
WHERE users.user_email = 'steve.downs@gmail.com'
AND communities.code = 'HX99f9'
```

I now want to replace the dummy email and community code data with the variables in the below php function, and submit it to the database.

This is my function:

```
public function insertNewAdminIntoCommunity($email, $code)
{
$sql = "insert into community_players (community_id, player_id) select communuities.id, users.id from communuities inner join users on communities.admin = users.user_email where users.user_email = '".$email."' and communities.code = '".$code."'";
$statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

if(!$statement) throw new Exception($statement->error);

$statement->bind_param("ss", $email, $code);
$returnValue = $statement->execute();

return $returnValue;
}
```

However it is throwing out errors back into Xcode - II thought maybe I have incorrect syntax when trying to use the variables in the function within the sql statement?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to use PDO? what is your connection object? Please also show errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not concatenate the variables into the SQL string, as you do here:

```
users.user_email = '".$email."' and communities.code = '".$code."'";
```

as that defeats the whole purpose of prepared statements. Prepared statements help protect against [SQL-injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), by allowing you to define placeholders that will be replaced with properly escaped values.

You should therefore use placeholders (question marks, without surrounding quotes):

```
users.user_email = ? and communities.code = ?";
```

What `$statement->bind_param("ss", $email, $code);` then does, is bind your variables to the two placeholders. Each `s` of the first argument signifies that the respective values should be treated as a string.<sup>1</sup> MySQL takes care of properly escaping the values this way.

The error therefore most likely is telling you that you are trying to bind values to non-existent placeholders.

---

1. See the [`mysqli_stmt::bind_param()` documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.bind-param-parameters) for more available options.

Answer (score 0):

You have a communuities  in some field and communities in others 
be sure you are using the proper table name in all  case

```
$sql = "insert into community_players (community_id, player_id) 
        select communuities.id, users.id 
        from communuities 
        inner join users on communities.admin = users.user_email 
        where users.user_email = '".$email."' and communities.code = '".$code. "'";
```

and i suggest the use PDO with binding param instead string concat ..(and others connections)